# Generate model description in AspNet WebApi help pages

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

How do I generate a **description** for my model in Asp.Net Web Api help pages?

Example:

[image]

As you can see from the example, I can already generate `Name`, `Type` and `Additional Information`. But how do I generate `Description`?

*I've tried nothing and I'm all out of ideas.*

No, that's not true. I've tried adding comments to my `TransactionDto` class, but it does not work.

```
/// <summary>
/// A DTO (Data Transfer Object) for Transaction objects.
/// </summary>
public class TransactionDto
{
    /// <summary>
    /// The manager who registered the transaction.
    /// </summary>
    public string FromId { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// The receiving manager.
    /// </summary>
    [Required]
    public string ToId { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Optional expiration date.
    /// </summary>
    public DateTime? Expires { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Date the transaction was created.
    /// </summary>
    public DateTime Created { get; set; }
}
```

I have configured `HelpPageConfig.cs` to use an `XmlDocumentationProvider` like so:

```
config.SetDocumentationProvider(new XmlDocumentationProvider(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/XmlDocument.xml")));
```

So how do I generate these descriptions for models?

Comment: Do you also have the following 'checked' in your project properties: `Properties | Build | Output | XML Documentation File`?

Answer (score 12):

I believe you have models in the separate project other than the Web API project?

If that is the case, the web API project is not aware of the help XML file generated for the models. you need to set the XML output path for both web API project and the models project and then combine both XML files in the register method of HelpPageConfig.cs file.

```
public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
{
        XmlDocument apiDoc = new XmlDocument();
        apiDoc.Load(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/WebApi.Orders.xml"));
        XmlDocument contractsDoc = new XmlDocument();
        contractsDoc.Load(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/Contracts.xml"));
        if (contractsDoc.DocumentElement != null && apiDoc.DocumentElement!=null)
        {
            XmlNodeList nodes = contractsDoc.DocumentElement.ChildNodes;
            foreach (XmlNode node in nodes)
            {
                XmlNode copiedNode = apiDoc.ImportNode(node, true);
                apiDoc.DocumentElement.AppendChild(copiedNode);
            }
            apiDoc.Save(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/WebApi.Orders.xml"));
        }
        config.SetDocumentationProvider(new XmlDocumentationProvider(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/WebApi.Orders.xml")));
    ......
}
```

Comment: Thanks and good thinking, my models were indeed in a different project.