# Empty model property description on ASP.NET Web API Help Pages

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2, asp.net-web-api-helppages

## Introduction

I've followed [this tutorial](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/getting-started-with-aspnet-web-api/creating-api-help-pages) to setup my ASP.NET Web API Help Pages.

Using `<package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.HelpPage" version="5.2.3" targetFramework="net452" />`

The documentation seems to be fine, but I'm getting **empty model property descriptions**.

They are empty in both controller method/endpoint and model details doc.

## Controller method example

```
/// <summary>
/// POST: api/remitent
/// </summary>
/// <param name="remitent"></param>
public void Post([FromBody]Remitent remitent)
{

}
```

## Model property example

```
/// <summary>
/// First name property summary
/// </summary>
[Required]
[MaxLength(49)]     
public string FirstName { get; set; }
```

## Results

I would expect the FirstName property summary to fill the model property description on docs. Instead the description column is empty:
[image]

---

Does anyone know how to solve that?

Comment: I have the same issue, did you find a solution?

Comment: @bit Unfortunately I didn't.

Comment: Experienced the same problem. If you peek into the generated xml file, there is no info about the models.

Comment: @MaximilianoEjberowicz see the answer to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30562235/generate-model-description-in-aspnet-webapi-help-pages

Comment: @foresightyj it works! Models and Web API were in different projects.

Comment: @MaximilianoEjberowicz you figured how to make it work when the models are in different project? I didn't have time to work on it after my reply.

Comment: @foresightyj Just put them together in the same project. Will try [this fix](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36261709/2174237) later.

Comment: @MaximilianoEjberowicz Cool :-)

Answer (score 2):

Did you uncomment this line of code in Areas/HelpPage/App_Start/HelpPageConfig.cs:

```
config.SetDocumentationProvider(new XmlDocumentationProvider(
    HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/XmlDocument.xml")));
```

Comment: Yes I did, followed all the steps mentioned in the tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

Can you use Swashbuckle instead of Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.HelpPage. I find Swashbuckle provides better documentation and friendly UI to explore your API. You can also use it to test your API.

Comment: I appreciate the [swashbuckle](https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle) alternative, seems to have a lot of features. I'm even using swagger docs for other projects. I will consider for the future, but would first like to solve the web api help issue.